# Print a triangle in bash using /, \ and _ given a dimension

Tags: bash

I've seen a lot of question very similar to this one, but I'm finding difficulties as most function in a different way than what I need to do.

What I'm trying to accomplish is print a triangle in bash using the /,\ and _ symbols. 
The example given to me is this one.

```
> Dimension? 
> 4  
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
--------
```

My code so far makes 2/3 of what I need, which is print the base, one side but I can't print the right side.

that's what I got

```
    #! /bin/bash 
read -p "DIM? " DIM
for((i=1; i<=$DIM-1; i++))
    do 
    #print the spaces 
    for((a=i; a<=$[$DIM-1]; a++))
    do
        echo -ne "*"; #im using * instead of spaces to see if everything works       
    done   
    echo "/" #this prints the side 

done 
 #print the base  
    for((i=1; i<=$[$DIM*2]; i++))
    do
        echo -ne "_";
    done
```

My output is

```
***/
**/
*/
________
```

I know I'm missing a nested for, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the dimension in your output example is  3 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be too much work for such a trivial task.
For each row except the base, you need to print `dim-nr` blanks (where `nr` is the number of row starting from zero), a forward slash, `nr*2+1` blanks, and a backslash. With arithmetic expansions `printf` can do all that in a single call.
For the base, `dim*2` dashes should be printed; again, `printf` can do that easily with a little help from `seq` (which is also available as a loadable bash builtin).

```
#!/bin/bash -
read -p $'Dimension?\n' dim
for ((nr=0; nr<dim-1; nr++)); do
  printf '%*s%*s\n' $((dim-nr)) '/' $((nr*2+1)) '\'
done
printf '%.s-' $(seq $((dim*2)))
printf '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks man! We just got introduced to bash scripting at uni, I was making it all way too complicated that it was.